# How to multiply a 3D numpy array in Python to get a 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization

Let's say I have the following array A, where the right-hand-side is its '.shape':

`A.shape = (10000, 10, 10)`

and I would like to get `C.shape = (10000,10)` such that:
for each 10x10 matrix in A (out of 10000 ones), it is reduced to a 1D vector (10,1) of the sum of each row, hence, the final result is `C.shape = (10000,10)`

Essentially, if we had shape (10,10) and multiplied by a `numpy.ones` vector (10,1) that would do the job.

But how to write this in Python when dealing with a 3D array (10000,10,10)?

end goal is shapes (10000,10,10) multiplied by **something** = (10000,10), where the second dimension of (10000,10) is now the row-sum of the previous (10,10) matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `.sum()` along axis 1 to get it from `(10000,10,10)` shaped array:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.ones(1000000).reshape(10000,10,10)
print(a.shape) # 10000,10,10
b=a.sum(axis=1)
print(b.shape) # 10000,10
c=b.sum(axis=1)
print(c.shape) # 10000,1
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I want, at least it doesn't add up when I manually go through an example like this

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is:

```
import numpy as np
C = np.sum (A, axis=2)
```

**Alternative Solution 1 (Reduce):**

If you want to use the `reduce()` function, use this:

```
import numpy as np
C = np.add.reduce (A, 2)
```

Here,`2` represents the axis along which the reduction happens, through the `add` operation.

For more details, refer [this](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html?highlight=numpy%20sum%20reduce)

This would probably work only from version 1.17 and above of `numpy`

**Alternative solution 2: (Multiply with ones vector)**

Use the `numpy.dot()`:

```
B = np.ones((10,), dtype=A.dtype)
C = np.dot (A,B)
```